# Adding a connection to all Excel files within a folder using Python

Tags: excel, powerquery, pywin32

I have a bunch of reporting models which I want to connect to a single input sheet.

The best way to do this will be for every model to be using the same query from an ODC file.

This way I can mange just the single ODC file and change all queries within all models. The issue I have is: I would like to place these models into a folder and be able to place a new connection to this ODC file.

I could manually do this, but I have 900 models and do not want to just this set up. Something like Python would help a ton for this.

Basically I need it to open the files hit "Data > Existing Connection > File path for ODC file > Query properties >  load > Save > Close

Do this for every model within a folder.

Let me know if y'all can think of anything. I have used Python a bit to refresh every data connection within a folder, but can't figure out how to modify it to get it to work.

Wish I could use office scripts and power automate, but that is not what I have available to me. So Python is what I shall use.

I have tried to look up documentation on the win32 library, but can't fin any functions for the get data from existing connections button in the excel ribbon.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.